# clear selected checkbox scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My HTML:

```
<div class="check"  ng-repeat="point in dbs">
       <input 
            name="db"
            id="{{point.id}}"
            ng-model="point.select" 
            ng-click="update($index, dbs)" 
            ng-checked="false"
            type="checkbox"
            ng-required="point.select" />
    </div>
```

Whilst my update() function looks like:

```
        $scope.update  = function(position, dbs) {
      angular.forEach(dbs, function(point, index) {
        if (position != index) 
          point.select = false;
      });
    }
```

This works as with regards to tracking what the selected checkbox is, and sending into another controller that expects the value, all is working good.

However, when I go back from the resulting page, back to this search form again, somehow the checkbox I selected before, is preselected, and I don't want anything to appear, rather just have everything blank.

Would it be as easy as simply stating:

```
$scope.point.select = null;
```

as I can't seem to find a good solution for this, so that the checkbox is always blank / not pre selected when you arrive on this form.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I get what you are doing.  It looks like you are trying to make your list of checkboxes mutually exclusive.  I might look at using a radio button list (a set of radio buttons with the same name attribute, HTML interprets this as a mutually exclusive list).  If you create a variable which will hold the value of the selected option and pass that value around, you probably can achieve the same result with less code.  Take a look here: https://jsbin.com/sunusihuse/edit?html,js,output
As for clearing the list of controls when you revisit the page, what I have described will do that too because the value of the variable which will hold the selected value is initialized to an empty string.  Hope this helps.